# send message to content script from background with delay ? chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to senMessage from background to content script , however the I want the background to send the message after a specific time  , here is my code :

***background :***

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.id == "openUrl") {
        var tabId = sender.tab.id;
        var url = msg.url;
        openUrl(tabId, url);
    } else if (msg.id == "background") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            chrome.tabs.query({
                active : true,
                currentWindow : true
            }, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {}, null);
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

I am receiving the bellow error :

```
**Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**
```

I am not sure , why the chrome api can get the selected tab ?

You can download the source file here  :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_Hkedx8ldAeRWiFKTj4YEv_bXFUt-3CY

Thank you .

Comment: try running the `tabs.query` immediately, and delaying the `tabs.sendMessage`

Comment: It's either a bug in the browser or your active window is devtools, in which case the observed behavior is correct.

Comment: @wOxxOm what do you mean "active window is devtools" could you please share more information ? Yes the developer mode on ! and I used load unpacked option